# Creating conditional properties in GraphQL type definition

Tags: types, graphql, apollo

I'm setting up a GraphQL server using the Apollo framework.

It will have an entity called `Shelf`. A `Shelf` has a `shelfId` and `packages`.

I need to be able to query for `Shelves` with the `shelfId` or `packageCode`.

My data source can handle both of these scenario's but I want to have 1 resolver called `shelf` for this.

Example

```
query getShelf(shelfId: "1") {
  shelfId
}
```

or:

```
query getShelf(packageCode: "123") {
  shelfId
}
```

How to can I define a type the checks if `packageCode` or `shelfId` is set?

- When `packageCode` is provided `shelfId` is not required
- When `shelfId` is provided `packageCode` is not required
- When neither us provided either of them are required

The only options I think I have are:

- A) Create separate resolvers for each scenario
- B) Make them both optional and return an error from the resolver.

How would I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no syntax at this time that would support making one of two arguments non-null. You'd have to make both arguments nullable and then add the validation logic to your resolver.

Alternatively, if both arguments are the same type, you can do something like this:

```
type Query {
  getShelf(id: ID! idType: ShelfIdType!)
}

enum ShelfIdType {
  SHELF_ID
  PACKAGE_CODE
}
```

I don't think that's necessarily better, but it is an option if you want to rely exclusively on GraphQL's type system for validation.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I did not consider using an enum for this yet and you are correct I only want to rely on GraphQL type system for validation.

Comment: That's not a pattern you'll really see in the wild because it's pretty limited and may be unintuitive to anyone consuming your API. But YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it with one resolver. Above mentioned answer by Daniel is also one of the ways.

You can have both as separate arguments as well.

```
type Query {
  getShelf(SHELF_ID: ID, PACKAGE_CODE:ID)
}
```

In the resolver, you can check which argument is present and write logic to fetch the data accordingly.